# D-link router management problem

Tags: macos, high-sierra, router

I have quite strange issue. I've bought new D-link router I can manage at 192.168.0.1 - I can log in into router interface but for some of subpages (in fact for most of them) I'm getting "Router not found". I'm using Wifi.

I've verified it on Ethernet on Windows - it's working fine. I've also verified it using Wifi on Windows tablet and it's also working fine.

Can be any MacOS system setting that is causing problem with this? Everything else is working pretty fine - I have connection to router all the time, Internet is working also fine.

Comment: Try connecting your MB via Ethernet and doable WiFi.  See if you can browse or not.

Comment: @Allan Unfortunately I don't have any USB -> Ethernet cable and Mac doesn't have RJ45 port by default :/

Comment: Then try in Safe Mode.  However, it might not be a bad idea to get a Mac compatible USB to Ethernet adapter  to have as a back up.  The idea here is you want to isolate whether it's a system issue (occurs on both Ethernet and WiFi) or if it's just an adapter issue (it only occurs on WiFi).  I'm betting it's the latter.